# Glassfish 3 and import signed SSL certificate issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, glassfish-3

I am trying to install a signed SSL certificate into Glassfish but I failed. Here is the list of steps

**1. I used keytool to generate new key pair (alias domain1)**

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keystore glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -validity 1000 -alias domain1
```

**2. Generate Certificate signing request (out - domain1.csr)**

```
keytool -certreq -alias domain1 -file **domain1.csr** -keystore glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
```

**3. I used OpenSSL to generate my own Root CA certificate**

3.1. Generate root CA private key ( out - rootCA.key )

```
   openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 1024
```

3.2. Creating certificate signing request (out - rootCA.csr )

```
   openssl req -new -key rootCA.key -out rootCA.csr
```

3.3. Self-sign rootCA.csr  ( out - rootCA.crt )

```
   openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in rootCA.csr -signkey rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt
```

**4. Sign domain1.csr ( generated from step 2) - ( out - domain1.crt)**

```
openssl x509 -req -days 500 -in domain1.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -out **domain1.crt** -CAcreateserial
```

**5. I have 2 signed certificates**

- rootCA.crt
- domain1.crt

**6. I need to install rootCA.crt, domain1.crt into Glassfish v3**

6.1. import **rootCA.crt** into /glassfish/domains/domain1/config/**cacerts.jks** with alias rootCA  ( Successfully)

```
    keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias rootCA -file rootCA.crt -keystore cacerts.jks
```

6.2. import **domain1.crt** into /glassfish/domains/domain1/config/**keystore.jks** with alias domain1  ( FAILED)

```
    keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias domain1 -file domain1.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

**At step 6.2. I received the error message:**

**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply**

Anyone knows what steps I am missing when I import rootCA.crt and domain1.crt into Glassfish?

**Since glassfish keystore.jks only stores Private keys so I am wondering that do I have to import self-signed rootCA.crt into keystore.jks?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are missing CA certificate in the keystore.jks. Try this after the step 6.1:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias rootCA -file rootCA.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```